# importanto pacote no Spyder, Python

Tags: python, numpy, spyder, ambiente

estou começando a aprender python. Então a primeira coisa q fiz foi instalar o python, nesse caso o ubuntu 16.04 LTS, já q nesse sistema o python já vem instalado.

Como primeiro teste, tentei rodar um simples programa com a biblioteca `numpy`, mas o programa n executa, exibe o seguinte erro:

```
import sitecustomize' failed; use -v for traceback
<type 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

Ao que me parece, o Spyder falhou em importar a biblioteca `numpy`, embora eu já a tenha chamado pelo terminal e ela veio, ou seja, está instalada.

Meu script é o seguinte:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Tue Jan 22 07:58:47 2019

@author: David
"""

import numpy as np
a = np.array([1, 2, 3])   
print(type(a))
```

Alguém por gentileza poderia me ajudar nesse problema ? Agradeço desde já.

Comment: Você deveria ter instalado o ubuntu 18.04 LTS já que o 16.04 é velho e já tem quase 3 anos que foi lançado. O seu problema parece ser na forma que está usando para rodar o script. Tente abrir um terminal e rodar o script diretamente no python, digitando `python meuscript.py`

Comment: Pois é - o Ubuntu tem uma versão nova  cada 6 meses, e o Python tem uma versão com grandes mudanças a cada 18 meses. Se vai instalar um sistema só pra Python, ponha o mais novo - Ubuntu 18.10 (e mesmo esse vem com a versão 3.6 do Python, já defasada).

Comment: Em seguida, preocupe-se com a linguagem, e não com uma IDE - até ter familiaridade com a linguagem

Comment: E por fim, veja alugm tutorial sobre "virtualenv" - e como criar ambientes isolados de Python com várias versões e bibliotecas difentes, de acordo com cada projeto.

Comment: obrigado pelas sugestões amigo.

Comment: Amigo, a importação do numpy que você fez foi pelo terminal do ubuntu ou foi pelo console o IPython no Spyder.

Answer (score 1):

Boa noite,

O seu problema não é afetado pela a versão do seu Ubuntu, o fato que deve ser visto é qual interpretador o seu Spyder está utilizando. A maioria das distros vem com o python por padrão, eu nunca encontrei nenhuma que não viesse com o python, ao  instalar o numpy pelo terminal o mesmo ficará disponível para o seu interpretador.

Porém caso você tenha utilizado o **Anaconda** por exemplo para **instalar o Spyder** ele acaba utilizando o interpretador do Anaconda, que é diferente do seu interpretador do seu SO, ou seja você acaba por ter dois consoles do python com a mesma verão porém diferentes.

Caso queira ver se o numpy está instalado no mesmo interpretador do Spyder basta importar no console do IPython no próprio Spyder.

[image: Ipython]

Caso queira mudar o interpretadpr padrão do Spyder basta ir em `Ferramentas -> Preferências(Ctrl + Alt + Shift + P) -> Interpretador Python` e selecionar o Interpretador desejado.

[image: Interpretador]